# How to call a payable function within a payable function from the same contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, contract-debugging, smart-contract-wallets

Imagine a contract with a 2 functions:

```
A.sol:
contract A{
    function buyItem()
    {
      #implementation
    }
    function buyItems()
    {
        for(#loop_conditions)
        {
            buyItem{value: item_price}();
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives an error because I am not allowed to call buyItem{value: item_price} as function call options are only allowed on externnal functions. How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call an external function but it will change msg.sender, also it will be a little more expensive.

I'd recommend to use an internal function that can invoke from both fucntions. Something like this:

```
contract A {
    function buyItem(bytes32 itemId) external payable {
        doBuyItem(itemId, msg.value);
    }
 
   function buyItems(bytes32[] memory items, uint256[] memory prices) external payable {
        for (uint256 i=0; i<items.length; i += 1) {
            doBuyItem(items[i], prices[i]);
        }
    }

    function doBuyItem(bytes32 itemId, uint256 price) internal {
         /* buy item */
    }
}
```

Comment: But in your for loop of BuyItems(), how do you pass a specific amount of money to doBuyItem() ?

Comment: @JohnyB I'd assume if you want to buy several items the individual prices will be included in a parameter of the transaction.

Comment: but that's exactly the problem I tried to describe here. I pass it as a parameter but because I am passing it to a function of the same contract, I get a compiler error. If I pass it to a function of another contract, then the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: @JohnyB Sorry, I've completed the example to show how I was assuming buyItems will be called.